# Почему результаты выдаются одинаковые?

Tags: pandas, машинное-обучение, dataframe, numpy, scikit-learn

[image]

Не могу понять почему три метода выдают одинаковые результаты

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что вы три раза вызываете `cross_val_score()` с одним и тем же `estimator` - `clf`, вместо того чтобы использовать `clf`,`clf1`,`clf2`. Скорее всего это результат `copy & paste`...